# Error with RestKit putObject with 204 response Xcode

Tags: objective-c, restkit-0.20

Im developing a iOS RESTFul client App but I´m in trouble with the 204 response for a PUT request, this is my code:

```
    [objectManager putObject:dataObject path:path
               parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                   NSLog(@"Register Success");
                   completionBlock(YES);
               } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"Register Failed %@", error);
                   completionBlock(NO);
               }];
```

Everything works, but I´m getting the following error:

```
E restkit.network:RKResponseMapperOperation.m:320 Failed to parse response data: Loaded an unprocessable response (204) with content type 'text/plain'
NSUnderlyingError=0x16ec4b60 "Cannot deserialize data: No serialization registered for MIME Type 'text/plain'", NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable response (204) with content type 'text/plain'}
response.body=No Content
```

I´m using pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.23.0'

I hope somebody knows how can I solve that
 Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How do you want to solve it? There is no data returned, so RestKit can't do any mapping. You need to teach it about the mime type, or just use AFNetworking to send the data (after mapping with RestKit). Or, get the server to respond with JSON mime type.

Comment: Hi Wain, thanks for your comment, do you have a sample snippet about the RKMapping on AFNetworking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is to tell RestKit to treat the text mime type as JSON:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/plain"];
```

Alternatively, use `RKMapperOperation` to serialise your object to be sent (or use the object manager to create the request to send) and then pass it on to the HTTP client (or enqueue an operation with the object manager). Check the RestKit github page for examples.